# Put a tag to a space which is between two constant words in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to select space which is between tow specific words and put some tag there. I am using XSLT 2.0

```
<chapter>
  <p type="Entry"><doc refType="anchor">
    <t/>Command K (ever publish)<t/></doc><ref format="Page Number" refType="anchor" refId="sec-sec_G"/>80
  </p>
</chapter>
```

Expected output :

```
<chapter>
  <p type="Entry"><doc refType="anchor">
    <t/>Command K<t/>(ever publish)<t/></doc><ref format="Page Number" refType="anchor" refId="sec-sec_G"/>80
  </p>
</chapter>
```

My expected output is, putting `<t/>` tag between `(ever publish)` and `Command K` strings. `(ever publish)` and `Command` are constants. The character `K` can be changed.

tried code :

```
<chapter match="[starts-with('command')]//text()[ends-with('(ever publish)')]/text()">
  <t/>
</chapter>
```

Tried code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the *identity template*. Due to template prioritization details,
it should be placed before the second template (see below).

Then your script should contain a template matching *text()* nodes, including
*xsl:analyze-string*.
The *regex* attribute should contain both "wanted" strings as capturing
groups with a space between them.

Inside should be:

- *xsl:matching-substring* printing:

  - group 1 (captured with the regex),
  - *<t/>* element (or whatever you want here),
  - group 2.
- *xsl:non-matching-substring*, just replicating the non-matched text.

Note that the second "wanted" string contains parentheses, which are
special regex chars, so to treat them literally, they should be escaped
with a `\`.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(Command K) (\(ever publish\))">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        <t/>
        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to filter out
unnecessary spaces.